# how to create own sdk from flutter project in visual studio code

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to ask some question about possible ways to create an a SDK from Flatter project.There is a project which has some methods that would be useful to give to another company that will reuse them in their project what it is the best way to do it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you make custom widgets and share them..

Comment: @Sirus Is there any way to give them some how compilated data?

Comment: What are you trying to do...I think making a SDK will be an overkill